# dojox.data.QueryReadStore. How to change index of array that contains data?

Tags: dojo

I get data from server:

```
store = new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({"url":"http://url_with_data"});
...
myGrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({"id":"myGrid2","selectionMode":"none","style":"height: 350px; width: 100%;","store":store,"structure":myGrid2Layout}), document.createElement('div');
```

In this example server must return json object where exists property "items", and this property contains all data. Example(php):

```
$a = array(
    'items' => array(....)
);    
echo json_encode($a);
```

The problem is that my server returns json with slightly different structure, like it:

```
$a = array(
    'result' => array(
         'items' => array(....)
    );
);
echo json_encode($a);
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend the QueryReadStore and override the _filterResponse function to manipulate the data you get back from the server.

```
dojo.declare("myQrs", [dojox.data.QueryReadStore], {
    _filterResponse: function(data) {
       //process/massage your data here
       return data
    }
});
```

See: http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/browser/dojo/tags/release-1.5.0/dojox/data/QueryReadStore.js and search for _filterResponse for some notes on this